# How To Grant View Definition of Object in SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

The tsql syntax throws an error about "view" in SQL Azure, but functions on SQL Server:

```
GRANT VIEW ON OBJECT dbo::foo TO [bar]
```

Can access be granted in SQL Azure to view the definition of an object outside of db_owner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  It should be

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON <object/schema> TO <user/role>
```

Example

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [bar]

GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON OBJECT::dbo.MyView TO [barRole]
```